# AutoLayout in DispatchQueue.main does not work

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a question about AutoLayout.

background => I want to arrange  UIImageView in UITableViewCell, make UIImageView asynchronously acquire an image, and dynamically change the height of the cell by AutoLayout with the aspect ratio of the image.
Where, UIImageView is on top of my custom UIView, which in turn is on Cell's ContentView.

AutoLayout works well with this code without any error.

```swift
private var contentHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

// this method called in constructor 
func setupAutolayout() {
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
    messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 16),
    messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
    messageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240),


    contentImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.topAnchor),
    contentImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.leftAnchor),
    contentImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.rightAnchor),
    contentImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.bottomAnchor)
  ])
}

// After view loaded, this method called
func something() {
  contentHeightConstraint = contentImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
  contentHeightConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

but using that code in DispatchQueue.main as async task(that will exec in Main thread), AutoLayout doesn't work well.
That causes `[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` error.

```swift
private var contentHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

// this method called in constructor 
func setupAutolayout() {
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
    messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 16),
    messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
    messageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240),


    contentImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.topAnchor),
    contentImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.leftAnchor),
    contentImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.rightAnchor),
    contentImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.bottomAnchor)
  ])
}

// After view loaded, this method called
func something() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // of course, exec in MainThread
    self.contentHeightConstraint = contentImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
    self.contentHeightConstraint.isActive = true
  }
}
```

this is that error messages(This error message only appears when running asynchronously） .

```
2019-03-31 13:10:06.791758+0900 app[42515:4243718] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a3dbd0 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fe775f3f830]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe775f3c210 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a3f1b0 UIView:0x7fe775f3f830.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe775f3c210.bottom - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a32a80 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fe775f40690]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe775f3f830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a32350 UIImageView:0x7fe775f40690.bottom == UIView:0x7fe775f3f830.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a2c190 UIImageView:0x7fe775f40690.height == 150   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a2d310 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe775f3c210.height == 116   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a2c190 UIImageView:0x7fe775f40690.height == 150   (active)>
```

**Point**
The point to note is that if you add constraints normally after the UIImageView's HeihgtAnchor it works as expected, but adding constraints asynchronously will it not work well.

**Additional info**
* table setting

```swift
table.estimatedRowHeight = 800
table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Comment: I forgot attach environment info :

Swift version => 4.2

Comment: backgrount?  `UITableCell`?

Comment: @ElTomato sorry I miss type.
backgrout => background
UITableCell => UITableViewCell

Comment: What height have you specified for your table view row?  There is a conflict between the height of your image and the height of the cell's content view.  You need to have automaticDimension for the cell height.

Comment: @Paulw11 Right, I already do that.  But it does not work. (I add additional info and program detail)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using bottom constraint and height at the same time? If so, that is not going to work.

You can try either by removing height constraint of `UIImageView` or bottom constraint of `UIImageView` to `UIView`.

Note:
Don't use view related code in background thread.